# How do I have more than 1 MySQL UPDATE queries on the same page?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have a problem with a page I'm building.
I have 2 buttons, each with the aim to UPDATE '*filelocation*' field in my MySQL table, *onClick*.

```
$setloc = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET filelocation='location1' WHERE username='$username'");
$setloc2 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET filelocation='location2' WHERE username='$username'");
```

So the above are my queries to UPDATE *filelocation* to either '*location1*' or '*location2*'; and below are the buttons which should execute either *$setloc* **or** *$setloc2* **onClick()**:

```
<div id='targetdiv'>
    <input class='destination' type='button' name='button1' onClick='<?php $setloc; ?>' value='Click here 1' /><br />
    <input class='destination' type='button' name='button2' onClick='<?php $setloc2; ?>' value='click here 2' /><br />
</div>
```

The problem is, you don't need to click any of the buttons to set the MySQL table's *filelocation* field. It automatically sets filelocation to *$setloc2*

How do I make it so that you have to hit a button in order to execute either $setloc or $setloc2; without it automatically setting filelocation to $setloc2.

Thanks a lot in advance,
hiroki

Answer (score 4):

You're doing it totally wrong. You php runs on the server. Your javascript runs on the client.

Basically the PHP output is sent to the client, so queries are run, and their output (which is nothing in ur case) is returned to the client on the PHP tags u opened on javascript events.
Check your HTML source to understand.

I suggest you read about HTTP's Request/Response nature to understand the difference between HTTP and Desktop Applications.

The right way to do it would be:

```
<?php 
if ($_GET['input']==1) 
   $setloc = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET filelocation='location1' WHERE username='$username'");
elseif ($_GET['input']==2)
   $setloc2 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET filelocation='location2' WHERE username='$username'");
else 
{
?>
<form method='get'>
<input type='submit' name='input' value='1' />
<input type='submit' name='input' value='2' />
</form>
<?php
}
```

Comment: hmm doesn't seem to work. Gonna try and see if i can get action='<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>' to make it work.